# Django Python UnicodeDecodeError ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: django, templates, utf-8, django-templates

I get the error:

```
('ascii', '[<Project: \xd0\x9f\xd0\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f>]', 11, 12, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
```

my template has only the following code:

```
{{project[0]}}
```

the project name is in Bulgarian.

The view has

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

the file itself is UTF-8 encoding as much as Coda can tell me.

What is causing the problem, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax should be: `{{ project.0 }}`

Comment: This makes no difference if I use `{{project.0}}` or `{{project[0]}}` Both give me unicode error

Comment: Do you have this in your settings.py: DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8' and
FILE_CHARSET = 'utf-8' ?

Comment: i have `DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8'` but no `FILE_CHARSET = 'utf-8' `. Added it. Made no difference. :(